# Oracle JDK to OpenJDK

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

So I am currently building all my applications in Oracle JDK 8. Will the Oracle Licensing policy update affect the use of JDK 8 or Is that only for JDK 11 LTS. Suppose If I want to migrate to JDK 11 in near future, Can I choose OpenJDK under GPL upto production? Is there any change in source code from Oracle JDK under BCL and OpenJDK under GPL? Can I use it interchangeably?

Comment: This is a legal question, so you shouldn't rely on answers you get here.  But they would be: 1) yes, 2) no, and 3) yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the most important part is a legal / business question, not programming question.

Answer (score 10):

OpenJDK is a word that means many things.

It all starts with OpenJDK, the source repository. It is GPL licensed (and that's a can of worms by itself, lots has been written about it, and the full license can be found [on the OpenJDK licenses page](https://openjdk.java.net/legal/).

But that's sources. There's the notion of 'packaging' the sources. This is, itself, a product. Perhaps if you're old enough you remember that folks would sell, shrink-wrapped in a box, a bunch of CDs or DVDs with a linux distro, a manual, and the right to support for a certain period of time. That is a packaging of an open source product. The fact that I can buy a SuSE distro in a box in the store doesn't make linux a for-pay product. The OpenJDK (the source repo) is no different.

A packaging of the OpenJDK (source repo) would presumably include, though all of these are optional components:

- Binaries for a few platforms, such as 'for windows', 'for ARM Linux', etc.
- An installer to install this binary.
- A channel to communicate updates to you, for example about security issues; this can be as simple as a mail newsletter and as complex as a continuously running tiny app that checks for updates and automatically installs them when an update shows up, to commitment to maintain an apt-get repo.
- Support, via phone, mail, etc. This support can be for the VM itself ("My VM crashes if I give it more than 4GB of memory") to programming java to trying to optimize a deployment ("Which garbage collector is more efficient here?") – to merely having a no-guarantees whatsoever forum.

There are many packagings of the OpenJDK (the source repo). The ones most relevant to you:

- Oracle OpenJDK, the product. This is free and open source (FOSS), ships with no support whatsoever (like most FOSS), does have installers and binaries for many platforms, is produced by oracle, and notably offers a support channel *ONLY* until the next major java version is released. Right now you can download Oracle OpenJDK11 and it'll be supported.. for a few weeks, because OpenJDK12 is around the corner. You may have heard of 'long term support' versions.. that doesn't apply to Oracle OpenJDK. In this product, 'long term support' just isn't a thing.
- Oracle JDK. This is a commercial offering (though it does have sort of a preview/developer version, but you're not supposed to use that for much, best to ignore its existence), that notably offers support from oracle for it, AND it *DOES* adhere to the long-term-support thing. In a few weeks, when Oracle OracleJDK12 is released, OracleJDK11 is still supported. As in, if a security issue comes up, they'd patch it and release an update, and make sure all your auto-updaters and such pick it up, and they'll mail you about it, etc.
- AdoptOpenJDK's JDKs. The adoptopenJDK project is an open source volunteer endeavour. These are free and they do commit to keeping JDKs updated, particularly the ones oracleJDK considers 'long term support' (so, 8 and 11), though notably they have NOT committed to *writing* patches. If there's an open source security or bugfix patch out there they'll apply it and release a new version, but if there's no such patch then there won't be an update.
- Amazon's [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) offerings. These are free; there's an 8 version and just this week an 11 has been released. Amazon's committed to keeping these up to date and specifically checked to run smoothly on amazon AWS instances.

(Some others are listed in Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK#OpenJDK_builds)

My advice is to use adoptopenjdk JDKs everywhere, except perhaps if you run java on AWS stuff you might want to pick up coretto instead. If your boss wants the safety cushion of support and SLAs, buy oracle's.

Use Oracle's OpenJDK packaging only for early access releases; if you want to test JDK12 on your dev machine, oracle openJDK is what you're looking for.

Legally speaking all of these offerings have their own licenses. AdoptOpenJDK, Coretto, and Oracle OpenJDK are all pretty much GPL+classpath exception and that's all, but, I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: The thing that is still uncertain (at least to me); Is if Oracle will be keeping a separate source repo for developing JDK 11 LTS after public support ends, or if those changes will be contributed to OpenJDK as well.

Comment: That sounds great! Still Is there any impact for the lower versions? Or support ends only for 11 LTS?

Comment: @vipin-ev As has _ALWAYS_ been the case, support for any given version eventually ends. The only change (starting with 9) is that this period is much shorter now. Oracle stuck to their promises on JDK8 support, but, that has by now ended (8 is old). AdoptOpenJDK and coretto still support their 8 release, as does OracleVM (that's for-pay). Oracle OpenJDK supports only 11, and in a few weeks, only 12.

Comment: Than you rzwitserloot and Jorn Vernee . That explains it well!

Comment: Be careful with the word "support".  People often say "support" when they mean "updates".  There are many places to get no-cost updates for OpenJDK-derived distributions, but if you actually want support, you're always had to pay _someone_ for it, whether that someone is Oracle or someone else.